# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, scripting

Where does RegisterStartupScript() actually put the JavaScript in the rendered document? We use this extensively to trigger JavaScript from the codebehind, and I've always wondered how the hell this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN:

> Similar to the
>   RegisterClientScriptBlock method, the
>   RegisterStartupScript method emits the
>   script just before the closing tag of
>   the Page object's 
>   element. Be sure to include opening
>   and closing  elements around
>   the script block string specified in
>   the script parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use comments to keep tracking your javascript code in rendered html.

Answer (score 0):

RegisterClientScriptBlock() writes script block right after the `<form runat="server">` tag.

RegisterStartupScript() writes script block right before the closing `</form>` tag.